# Android Firebase-Analytics : Not able to set null to userid and userproperty

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I'm using below code snippet to clear userid and userproperty value by setting "null" but the value is getting retaining in GoogleAnalytics, Firebase.

```
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context).setUserId(null); 
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context).setUserProperty("sessionId", null);
```

Userid and sessionid value will get set if user loggedin and if user logout userid and sessionid values needs to be clear.

Can anyone help me to sort out this issue

Thanks,
Kamal

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: even [Google's documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#public-void-setuserproperty-string-name,-string-value) says that passing in `null` should clear the user property, but it's also not working for me either

Answer (score 3):

I hit the same bug and opened a GitHub issue.I got that answer:

"It looks like the issue isn't the setUserId not working. The user id is indeed removed, but the debugView isn't showing this, so this is a UI issue. "

Monitor the issue here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/3602

Comment: I believe the issue is still not resolved. Did you (or anyone) get any workarounds?

Comment: @SlickSlime. Yes, it is still not fixed. My workaround was to set userID to "null"(As string "null"), instead of actual null. Or just change it to something that doesn't mean anything like "xxx". That is not the best solution but at least clearing the actual userID to honor privacy concerns.

Comment: This issue is sadly not yet fixed in 2024