# Firebase: Setting User Property to Null or blank value not deleting the userproperty

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am trying to delete or set the user properties when I logout from the app but after setting the user properties to null or blank user properties still persist in Firebase console.

This is code snippet I am trying.

```
    mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserId(null)
    mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("user_age", null)
    mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("user_gender", null)
    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseConstants.Events.LOGOUT, bundle)
```

Comment: Most likely reason that you do not `await` for all these functions

Comment: i am also running into this issue... this SO question also seems similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53077408/android-firebase-analytics-not-able-to-set-null-to-userid-and-userproperty